# curve fit for large data set

Tags: regression, curve-fitting

Need to find curve/trendline and equation that fits the large data set. Looks as in the scatter plot given below. any suggestion in a particular direction are appreciated. Any libraries in java or python or any online tools. I have tried excels trendline option, but the equation underfits my data.[image: x:price, y:time in days, total instance :8000]

Comment: Try localized regression. If you're happy working with Python, you can use http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess.html

Comment: is there any way that u know of, to get the resulting equation for the fit?

Comment: Nah, I don't like to use Python for stats stuff. A simple Google search should help you out though.

Comment: Notice that the spread is related to the mean, If there are no exact zeros, it's probably worth taking log(y), and looking at that. It may also be worth considering log(x), but it depends on what it actually measures as to whether that will also make sense (if the origin is arbitrary, it probably doesn't). What do the y and x variables consist of?

Comment: x is price , y is time

Answer (score 0):

That looks like data you want to transform first and then maybe try a linear model. My first guess would be to try regressing $y$ against $1/x$

Comment: $1/x$ is a special guess. I would suggest to try to find the "best" transformation with the Box-Cox method. Beware that transformations like $1/x$ or $\log(x)$ do not work when $x$ is zero, and you should tranform $x\to 1+x$ beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy is hard to decide on without more details about the question. But the simplest reasonable option would be to log-transform $y$ and then regress against $x$. Since $y$ is price, zeroes are unlikely. But if zeroes are present, a square root transform should work instead.

If the relationship is not linear or something simple like exponential, a spline or local regression (such as LOESS) would work.